# Why "fall asleep to the music" not "fall asleep with the music"?

Tags: prepositions

Why "fall asleep to the music" not "fall asleep with the music"?

I think `with` would be better but there's nobody use `with` in this case. Why? How should I pick the prep word?

Comment: Asking "why" for language usage often does not really help. Language communities have their habits, and they are often a bit arbitrary. Like history. It has just so developed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we discuss an activity done while a sound or sounds are being made (for example, while music is playing), we use the 'to' preposition: dance, hum, tap fingers, move, etc **to** the music.

> to
>   preposition (AT THE SAME TIME AS)
>   at the same time as music or
>   other sound:
>   I like exercising to music.
>   He left the stage to the
>   sound of booing.

[To (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to)